# How to diplay BOTH the tick AND the axis label in an asp.net chart?

Tags: asp.net, charts

I have not been able to display both the tick and the axis label for my asp.net BoxPlot chart -- as you can see, I've set the `chart.ChartArea[0].AxisY.MajorTickMark.Interval = 1;` just to make it obvious. What I want is to show the number next to each tick, but the interval for displaying the numbers seems to be stuck at 50. I thought by changing the interval, it would also display the number.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was setting the Interval in my `boxChart_PrePaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)` hook, and then I read the documentation closer -- the prepaint method fires AFTER the background of the chart is drawn, so I assume the `chart.ChartArea[0].AxisY` tick marks are part of that background rendering.

Now I'm setting the interval where I'm also constructing the chart, and it is rendering the number along with each tick.

[image]